# Jersey ManagedAsync vs User defined ThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

So when I was trying to understand jersey's Async Suspend what I understood is that we need a separate Thread/Executor Service. I also understand that jersey provides @@ManagedAsync in which case these threads are managed by Jersey. 
This feels like @ManagedAsync should be the ideal way to go as it abstracts and probably would have the best implementation underneath. But this is just my feeling. So my question is when would we go with the @ManagedAsync method and when would we work with our out ThreadPool/ExecutorService for the Async threads.?